# How to get text highlighting of ractivejs template scripts in phpstorm?

Tags: syntax, phpstorm, highlighting, ractivejs

I am using ractivejs with php project and PHPStorm 8.0.2.

However, when I use a ractivejs script all the text within that script is white and not highlighted. This is different from what happens with a javascript script.

I am attaching a screenshot so that you guys can get the idea.

[image]

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to get the syntax highlighting just as if it was a Javascript? (Changing the file extension is not what I want in case you find that solution)

Thanks,

Andrés

P.S. I have searched a lot but if you guys can also point me to the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/458724?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

Use `type="text/html"`. You might get some warnings, e.g., about invalid attributes, but it's the best you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the type attribute from the script tag so that it is just:

```
<script id="template>
</script>
```

Ractivejs will still be able to work on the page and you will get the text highlighting from phpstorm.

[image: Text highlighting of ractivejs code in phpstorm]

Comment: Doesn't that make the browser complain about the contents of the tag as it tries to parse as javascript?